# Get Third Level Categories WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am Trying To get Third Level WooCommerce Categories Here Is My Code:

```
$args = array(
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'show_option_none' => '',
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'parent' =>18,
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
    );
    $subcats = get_categories($args);
    echo '<div class="wooc_sclist">';
    foreach ($subcats as $sc) {
        $link = get_term_link($sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy);
        echo '<ul><a href="' . $link . '">' . $sc->name . '</a></ul>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
    wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 1):

i Solved it

```
      $args = array(
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'show_option_none' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'parent' => $number = 16,
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
);
$subcats = get_categories($args);
echo '<div class="wooc_sclist">';
foreach ($subcats as $sc) {
    $link = get_term_link($sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy);
    echo '<ul><a href="' . $link . '">' . $sc->name . '</a>'.$sc->term_id;
    $args2 = get_terms('product_cat',array(
        'child_of' => $sc->term_id,
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'hide_empty' => 1,
    ));
    foreach ($args2 as $subsubCats) {
        $SubLinks = get_term_link($subsubCats->slug, $subsubCats->taxonomy);
        echo '<li>sub - <a href=' . $SubLinks . '>' . $subsubCats->name . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
echo '</div>';
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: where do you paste this?

Comment: I creating a custom menu WordPress for dropdown here is the link [link] (http://knproducts.com.pk)